# Calling JS function using "arguments" for multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, arguments

this is my very first question asked here,  please, forgive my little knowledge of the subject I'm asking on and my bad english :)

Here is my problem: I need to call the following JS function (the enclosed code works as it is, when passing to it named and numbered params) but I don't know "a priori" how many parameters it could receive from the calling code.

I searched and understood that in such a case, it is possible to use "arguments", which should act as a "container" for a non specified number of parameters.

Unfortunately I know really little about JS and I'm going mad especially with its syntax and semantic (to now, to me too critpic).

Is there someone willing to help me shed some light about how to correctly write transmitting and receiving JS statements for this code snippet?

Or, at least, point me to some sample code I can easily understand and work on by myself?

Thank you all in advance, any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Here is the code I'm  talking about:

```js
<script>


Number.prototype.padDigit = function() { return (this < 10) ? '0'+this : this; }
//function timeSummation(id1, id2, id3, id4, id5) {
 
 function timeSumLUN(arguments) {
  var t1 = document.getElementById(OLUN_1).value.split(':');
  var t2 = document.getElementById(OLUN_2).value.split(':');
  var t3 = document.getElementById(OLUN_3).value.split(':');
  var t4 = document.getElementById(OLUN_4).value.split(':');
  var t5 = document.getElementById(OLUN_5).value.split(':');
  
 
  
  var mins = Number(t1[1])+Number(t2[1])+Number(t3[1])+Number(t4[1])+Number(t5[1]);
  var hrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
  hrs = Number(t1[0])+Number(t2[0])+Number(t3[0])+Number(t4[0])+Number(t5[0])+hrs;
  mins = mins % 60;
  return hrs.padDigit()+':'+mins.padDigit();
 
}

</script>
```

```html
echo "<td nowrap><input type='text' class='table_font'  size='5' maxlength='5' value='".$_ore_lavorate_LUN."' name='OLUN[]' id='OLUN_".$placeholder_id_cella."' 
   onchange='document.getElementById('somma_LUN').value = timeSumLUN(".$_placeholder_timeSumLUN_finale.")'></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `arguments` object is treated specially in a function body when that function is executed. Regardless of the formal parameters of a function declaration, e.g. `function(param1, param2) {}`, the `arguments` object is always available and will always reflect the arguments passed to the function at *runtime*. You must not specify it as a formal parameter (i.e. `function(arguments) {}`), just reference it in the function body:

```
function() {
  arguments.length; // the number of args received at runtime.
}
```

The `arguments` object can be used as an array, it can be iterated to access all passed arguments, but it really is not an array, but a specially treated object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Thank you @marekful I'm going to look at suggested resource ;)